# PRISM modules with multiple assemblies per module

Tags: wpf, prism

I have a WPF application that uses a layered architecture with three conventional layers: User Interface, Business Logic, and Data Layer. Now I have a requirement to split the application into vertical slices by functional areas (e.g. Customer, Product, Order). Meanwhile I would like to keep the horizontal layer separation within each vertical slice.

I am considering to use the PRISM modularity framework to accomplish this. So each functional area (vertical slice) will be represented as a PRISM module. But since my modules have a layered architecture, each module may consist of multiple assemblies.

Based on the PRISM documentation the ModuleCatalog assumes that each module is in one assembly. I am not sure how I can group multiple assemblies as one module. Any ideas if this can be done?

**Edit** -- I missed to mention that I want to de-couple the layers by not directly referencing the implementing assemblies for the layers. Instead I define the interfaces in an interface project for the respective layer such that only the interface project is referenced by the layer using it. Given this I still need a way to tell a module about the implementing assemblies for its layers.

Answer (score 2):

You're over thinking it.  Your other assemblies will just be references in your Module project.  You will only add the module to the ModuleCatalog, and as long as you have your referenced assemblies in place it will work as expected.

Comment: Hi Brian, I missed to mention that I want to de-couple the layers by not directly referencing the implementing assemblies for the layers. Instead I define the interfaces in an interface project for the respective layer such that only the interface project is referenced by the layer using it. Given this I still need a way to tell a module about the implementing assemblies for its layers.

Comment: Your main answer triggered another question: would you recommend a separate project to define the module class? I was thinking about having the module class in the UI layer project. Is there a recommended practice for structuring a layered module?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you are only referencing the interface assembly only.  As long as you have registered your implementations with the container, it will just work at runtime.

Comment: Once again, you are over thinking modules.  There are no "layered" modules. Modules are just major functional areas of your app. They can depend on other modules or stand alone. Services aren't modules, even if they are used in a module. You can use a module to register all your services if you like, but there are other ways to do that too.

Comment: I am sorry but I might be missing something. If a functional area of an app has a UI, its own services, and data repositories, why can't these be organized into layers and be considered as a one functional area module? (e.g. this functional area is developed by a separate team). I would expect that services are part of the functional area module and only when the module is initialized its services are registered in the container. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Of course if you are not sharing services, and they are only used in a single module, then you can place them all in the module, but you said you wanted to decouple the implementation, which means you aren't including the module services in the module directly.  So you have to register those with the container in either the shell or another services module. Just make sure your services are registered with the container before you load the module.